# How to install nodejs on redhat without internet and without root permission?

Tags: node.js, linux, redhat

What is the best way that Node.js can be installed on linux without internet nor root permissions.
So far I just downloaded the source tar.gz and tar.xz files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install nodejs on linux without root permission and offline

Download the tar.xz from Linux Binaries(x64) @ https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Then in ~.bashrc add:

```
NODE_HOME=~/apps/node-v12.18.3-linux-x64
PATH=$NODE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Source the bashrc file or restart terminal and you are done

```
source .bashrc
```

Try

```
node --version
npm -v
```

Comment: many thanks, its dont worke for me, I test it "~/apps/node-v12.18.3-linux-x64" and worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the rpm from nodesource website for specific redhat version and specific node version ex: https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_14.x/el/7/x86_64/ provides the rpm for node 14 on redhat 7